# Form's controls don't update on DataSet change

Tags: sql, vb.net

I can see the DataGridView changes fine but the Form's controls don't update.
From what I can tell the `bs.ResetBindings(False)` should trigger the update!
I've tried binding the controls from the property bindings tab as well with same result!

However I must confess this my first attempt at vb.net!

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        testdatTableAdapter.Fill(DATAHUBDataSet.testdat)
        bs = New BindingSource

        address.DataBindings.Add("text", bs, "address")
        typep.DataBindings.Add("text", bs, "type_projet")
        env.DataBindings.Add("text", bs, "enveloppe")
        ra.DataBindings.Add("text", bs, "region")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'If Not IsNothing(ds.Tables("testdat")) Then
        '    ds.Tables.Clear()
        'End If

        da = Nothing
        ds = Nothing
        qry = "Select * from work.testdat where network = "
        qry &= "'" & resstrb.Text & "'"
        con.Close()
        con.Open()
        'qry = "Select * from work.testdat"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, con)
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "testdat")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("testdat")
        bs.ResetBindings(False)
    End Sub
End class

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
'! note to mod, can't get this last bit of code to work with ctrl K 
Module test_sqldata
    Public str As String = getconstring()
    Public con As New SqlConnection(str)
    Public cmd As SqlCommand
    Public da As SqlDataAdapter
    Public ds As DataSet
    Public bs As BindingSource
    Public qry As String

    Public Function getconstring() As String
        Return "Data Source=XXXXXXX\YYYYYYYY;Initial Catalog=DATAHUB;Integrated Security=True"
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: You need to set your `BindingSource.DataSource` to the DataTable. Then use the Bindingsource as the DataSource of your DataGridView. The Controls' Binding will then work as expected. You may need to add an event handler to the `Binding.Parse()` event if you want the updates to occur in real-time. Otherwise, the controls' Binding will be updated only when you *change* Row/Leave a Cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either bind your 'bs' to the ds.datatable or remove the 'bs' and bind your textboxs to 'ds.Tables("testdat")' If you look you can clearly see that the grid and textboxs are using 2 differnt datasources, the bindingsource datasource is not being set at all so the textboxs are bound to an empty bindingsource

Comment: AS I said I'm new to VB.NET and am having difficulty figuring out how to set bs to ds.Tables("testdat") .  If datasource is not set then why does it display the correct record in datagridview? Is it set by default?

Comment: I dont have time to get into the problems in your code. It looks like youre excercising 2 styles of development, in one hand you're using the designer and dragging DataSet objects to the surface which adds the TableAdapter and much more generated code, much of which you dont see, and then youre trying to manipulate that code, or add more, whcih is not a good idea. Look at your TextBox binding VS your Grid binding, can you clearly not see they are on separate datasources? You need to set the bindingsource datasource to the table and use the bindingsource for both controls.

Comment: You really need to back up though and learn what youre doing. You dont want to get into a position where youre just slapping code around until it works, you wont learn anything.

Comment: I didn't realize that there could be hidden code. So I dumped everything and started over! Works great now!  The only visible code now tableadapter.fill on load and the filter used to update the dataset in the event handler!

Comment: I tried to use and example off the net and modify it. So I was mixing things up without knowing!   So thanks for the heads up!